# Expected object of type torch.FloatTensor but found type torch.cuda.FloatTensor for argument #2 'weight'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Firstly I have used like 'model.cuda()' to convert model and data to cuda. But it still has such a problem. I debug every layer of the model, and weights for every module has iscuda=True. So does anyone know why there is such a problem?

I have two models, one is resnet50 and another one which contains the first one as backbone.

```
class FC_Resnet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model, num_classes):
        super(FC_Resnet, self).__init__()

        # feature encoding
        self.features = nn.Sequential(
            model.conv1,
            model.bn1,
            model.relu,
            model.maxpool,
            model.layer1,
            model.layer2,
            model.layer3,
            model.layer4)

        # classifier
        num_features = model.layer4[1].conv1.in_channels
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(num_features, num_classes, kernel_size=1, bias=True))

    def forward(self, x):
        # children=self.features.children()
        # for child in children:
        #     if child.weight is not None:
        #         print(child.weight.device)
        x = self.features(x)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x

def fc_resnet50(num_classes=20, pre_trained=True):
    model = FC_Resnet(models.resnet50(pre_trained), num_classes)

    return model
```

And another one:

```
class PeakResponseMapping(nn.Sequential):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(PeakResponseMapping, self).__init__(*args)
        ...

    def forward(self, input, class_threshold=0, peak_threshold=30, retrieval_cfg=None):
        assert input.dim() == 4
        if self.inferencing:
            input.requires_grad_()

        class_response_maps = super(PeakResponseMapping, self).forward(input)

        return class_response_maps
```

And the main is very simple:

```
def main():
    dataset = VOC(img_transform=image_transform())
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)

    model = peak_response_mapping(fc_resnet50(), win_size=3, sub_pixel_locating_factor=8, enable_peak_stimulation=True)
    model=model.cuda()

    for step, (b_x, b_y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        b_x.cuda()
        b_y.cuda()

        result = model.forward(b_x)
```

Answer (score 4):

Somewhere down in the stack trace, Torch is expecting a CPU tensor (`torch.FloatTensor`) but is getting a GPU / CUDA tensor (`torch.cuda.FloatTensor`).

Given a tensor `tensor`:

- `tensor.to('cpu')` returns the CPU version of the tensor
- `tensor.to('cuda')` returns the CUDA version of the tensor

To write hardware-agnostic code:

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

Then you can do:

```
tensor.to(device)
```

For the OP, this becomes:

```
result = model.forward(b_x.to(device))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign `b_x.cuda()` back to `b_x`:

```
b_x = b_x.cuda()
b_y = b_y.cuda()
```

Looking at the documentation of [`.cuda()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.cuda):

> Returns a copy of this object in CUDA memory.

so, `b_x.cuda()` returns a *copy* of `b_x` and does not affect `b_x` in an  *in-place* manner.